# Android HttpPost with long URI

Tags: php, android, http-post

I'm trying to send data to my server using `HttpClient` in the following code.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL_PREFIX + "?" + URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "utf-8"));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
      }
      catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }).start();
```

but when I try to post this data to the server I get a 404 error code, the request fails and when I try to check the link using the browser I get the following.

```
Request-URI Too Long
The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.
Additionally, a 414 Request-URI Too Long error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
when check my httppost uri link length was 3497 char.
```

In my code I try to send base64 encoded image and some other parameters. Can anyone help me to solve this? or any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put params to the url for the POST request, put it in the body.

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL_PREFIX);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
```

GET requests parameters go to the url.
POST requests parameters usually go to the body.